# developing an llvm pass with cmake out of llvm source directory

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am trying to develop an llvm pass under my project directory. For that, I follow the info in http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#developing-llvm-pass-out-of-source. I create my CMakeFiles appropriately as in this link and my final project directory is like;

```
|-- src
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- bigForPass
|   |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |   |-- bigForPass.cpp
|   |   |-- merged.bc
|   |-- build
```

I also linked my source files with llvm root directory without any problem.
Finally I make the build under the 'build' folder and my shared library is created successfully with no problems (under build/bin folder) with the name LLVMHello1.dylib. 
However, when I try to run my pass over merged.bc file (which contains my llvm code) with the command

```
opt -load ../build/bin/LLVMHello1.dylib -bishe_insert <merged.bc> final.bc
```

I keep getting the error;

```
Error opening '../build/bin/LLVMHello1.dylib': dlopen(../build/bin/LLVMHello1.dylib, 9): Symbol not found: __ZTIN4llvm10ModulePassE
  Referenced from: ../build/bin/LLVMHello1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ../build/bin/LLVMHello1.dylib
  -load request ignored.
```

Any ideas and suggestions on this appreciated ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8):

from http://www.jiang925.com/node/28

> Undefined Symbol: _ZTIN4llvm12FunctionPassE There is an inconsistency
>   between LLVM main build system and the cmake support for building
>   out-of-source. The LLVM binaries are built without runtime type info
>   "-fno-rtti". Therefore, the out-of-source passes have to be built the
>   same way otherwise opt will complain that symbol
>   "_ZTIN4llvm12FunctionPassE" is undefined.
>
> To solve this problem, LLVM must be compile with RTTI enabled. Add
>   "-DLLVM_REQUIRES_RTTI=1" to cmake, or add "REQUIRES_RTTI=1" to make.

So I added `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -fno-rtti")` to CMakeLists.txt of my pass library and then it's working.