# Internal LLVM syntax errors when following Pass tutorial using CMake

Tags: cmake, llvm, llvm-clang

I am attempting to follow the tutorial [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) for developing a "Hello, World" LLVM pass - I am using the guidelines linked by that tutorial [here](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#developing-llvm-passes-out-of-source) for doing so out of the LLVM source directory. However, when I attempt to follow this tutorial, CMake reports a number of errors internal to LLVM itself.

I have the following directory structure:

`HelloWorld/
    CMakeLists.txt
    HelloWorld/
        CMakeLists.txt
        HelloWorld.cpp`

My `HelloWorld.cpp`, and the two `CMakeLists.txt` are copy and pasted directly from the tutorials linked to above.

I run `CMake HelloWorld` and it successfully generates a CMake configuration. However, when I run `make`. I get numerous errors reported from within the LLVM codebase itself.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LLVMPassName.dir/Vectorize.cpp.o
In file included from /Volumes/andromeda/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/Pass.h:377:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/PassSupport.h:27:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/PassRegistry.h:20:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm-c/Core.h:18:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm-c/Support.h:17:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:57:3: error: "Must #define
      __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
# error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
  ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:61:3: error: "Must #define
      __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before "         "#including Support/DataTypes.h"
# error "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before " \
```

The list goes on and on and all of them refer to errors in LLVM header files. This is a clean install of LLVM using Homebrew. To get linking to work, I had to set `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to the Homebrew include directory for LLVM.

My first thought was that CMake was attempting to use a different compiler (Clang vs. GCC or vice versa), but setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to point to either my `clang` or `g++` installation did not help.

Does anyone have any ideas for what might be the problem here?

---

After following the link provided by @oak in the comments, I was able to get rid of the first two Support/DataType errors. However, many of the errors still remain.

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/Pass.h:377:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/PassSupport.h:27:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/PassRegistry.h:21:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:543:63: error: a space is required
      between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
          typename BucketT = detail::DenseMapPair<KeyT, ValueT>>
                                                              ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:694:63: error: a space is required
      between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
          typename BucketT = detail::DenseMapPair<KeyT, ValueT>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#error "Must #define \_\_STDC\_LIMIT\_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965870/error-must-define-stdc-limit-macros-before-including-support-datatypes-h)

Comment: How I would pass those command line arguments via CMake? I've unsuccesfully attempted to get CMake (or the resulting Makefile) to incorporate these into the build process.

Comment: [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much research, it turns out that there is an inconsistency with how LLVM and CMake support out-of-source builds. The LLVM binaries are built with `-fno-rtti`, so CMake will complain about missing symbols unless it is also uses `-fno-rtti` when compiling the LLVM pass.

I fixed all of my troubles (including those solved by the temporary fix proposed by Oak) by adding `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -fno-rtti")` to my CMakeLists.txt file in the innermost directory.

This was inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225956/developing-an-llvm-pass-with-cmake-out-of-llvm-source-directory) also on StackOverflow.